# How to generate same symmetric key using same password and salt when using CryptNG

Tags: security, winapi, cryptography, bcrypt, encryption-symmetric

I am using Microsoft bcrypt (aka BestCrypt, Cryptgraphy Next Generation, Cryptography NG, CryptNG) library to generate symmetric keys:

- [**BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgeneratesymmetrickey)
- [**BCryptKeyDerivation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptkeyderivation)

But every time I get a different key. Even when the password and salt are the same. Is there any randomization added by these APIs?

If yes, What is the way to generate the same symmetric keys using the same entropy?

I tried below APIs:

- **[BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptopenalgorithmprovider)**
- **[BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgeneratesymmetrickey)**
- **[BCryptKeyDerivation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptkeyderivation)**

Comment: Can the second key you get decrypt data encrypted with the first key?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736635/why-bcryptderivekeypbkdf2-return-status-invalid-parameter   Does it help?

Comment: My mistake guys. I was printing the key in incorrect way. so the same entropy generates the same key. Thanks and sorry for the trouble.